# ParametricPlot3D returns an empty plot whereas Plot3D works

Tags: plotting

I would like to make a `ParametricPlot3D` of the solution of a Laplace equation in a circular area, so I write in the notebook the following:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = 0 == D[u[r, s], {r, 2}] + D[u[r, s], r] / r + D[u[r, s], {s, 2}] / r^2;
bc = u[1, s] == s;

nsol = NDSolve[{eqn, bc}, u[r, s], {r, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 2 π}]
```

Now I can obtain the solution surface with the command `Plot3D`:

```
Plot3D[u[r, s] /. nsol, {r, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 2 π}]
```

However, I cannot obtain a parametric plot with this:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[s], r Sin[s], u[r, s] /. nsol}, {r, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 2 π}]
```

The expression above just returns an empty graph... Not even a message that I  make a mistake! How can I fix it?

Comment: Try `u[r, s] /. First@nsol` in your parametric plot.

Comment: @MarcoB, Thanks a lot , it works now!!! By the way do you know why that happens?

Comment: I expanded on it in an answer below. It grew too long for a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve your problem, use `u[r, s] /. First@nsol` in your `ParametricPlot3D` expression.

Solutions from the `Solve` functions are returned as lists of lists (e.g. `{{u[r, s] -> InterpolatingFunction[...]}}` to accommodate cases in which multiple solutions for multiple variables may be present. For consistency, this happens even when a single solution is returned.

If you use that result directly in your replacement `{r Cos[s], r Sin[s], u[r, s] /. nsol}`, you get `{r Cos[s], r Sin[s], {InterpolatingFunction[...]}}` (notice the extra brace), which is not a format that `ParametricPlot3D` understands, so it returns unevaluated. To remove the extra nesting, you can use `First @ nsol` in your code instead.

On the other hand, when you do the same in `Plot3D[u[r, s] /. nsol, {r, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 2 π}]` the result is: `Plot3D[{InterpolatingFunction[...]}, ...]`. the `Plot` functions can accept a list of functions to plot, so your resulting list of *one* function is a perfectly valid input and it works on this case.